# Woocommerce Canceled Order Notification email to admin

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Greatings,

I'm getting about new orders email properly, emails about account creation. But then order is cancelled ADMIN don't get emails about that.

In Woocommerce settings i checked emails for Cancelled order everything is fine. But system don't sends. I dont need for customers to get that but as site admin i want to get theese emails.

How can i achieve that or it's Woocommerce bug and somehow i can manage with function or Plugin?

Comment: Also I've checked email outgoing from WP Mail log plugin - but there is no line about Cancelled emails at all. So in other words system wont sending at all

Answer (score 2):

Was the order moved from Pending to Cancelled? WooCommerce no longer sends an email to the admin for that (I think the logic is that a lot of bot-created Pending orders were automatically cancelled and giving admins too many notifications). You can restore the old behavior by hooking `woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_cancelled_notification` and calling `WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Cancelled_Order']->trigger` with the order ID.

If that doesn't explain what you're seeing, can you elaborate on the state the orders are in, and how they are being cancelled?